# How to realize a monthly window in apache flink?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Does flink only have windows of the same length? How can I use window of variable size to do monthly job in flink stream?

Comment: Did you try doing anything? Got through this link -  https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/windows.html 
and try doing what you want to achieve, may be then we can help

Comment: I can't find the window type I want,because  the time of a month is different from each other.Do you understand what I mean?

Answer (score 2):

Most of what you need is already there; what's missing is a window assigner that knows how to construct windows of the appropriate (and variable) durations. Assuming you want to operate in event time, you could base this on [TumblingEventTimeWindows](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-streaming-java/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/windowing/assigners/TumblingEventTimeWindows.java), and modify the assignWindows method to do the right thing.